# Insert multiple data with many to many relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have four models with many to many relationship
  **Users** 
      -id
     -Email 
     -Password 
  **Student**
     -id
     -Name
     -school
     ---------
  **Subject**
     -id
      -subname
   **Topic**
     -id
     -topName
     -sub_id
     --------
  When they broke down produce their respective pivot tables
    i.e
  -**student_user**
      -id
       -student_id
       -user_id
  -**student_subject**
     -id
     -studdent_id
     -subject_id
     -subject_name
  -**student_topic**
    -id
    -student_id
    -topic-id
    -topic_name
    -.........
I want to insert them with multiple selecting of the inputs i.e subject and topics must more than one.
What i failed is how to insert them into a data at the same time with such kind of relation since i used for each loop and i failed to figure out what attribute i can use to??
Topics and subjects datas are insided DB inserted already

Help

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="table_tuition_fee">
                                                    <thead>
                                                         <tr>
                                                             <td><label for="subject">Subject</label></td>
                                                             <td><label for="topic">Topic</label></td>
                                                             <td><label for="Amount">Amount</label></td>
                                                             <td><a class="bg-light btn btn-info addRow" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                     <tbody>
                                                         <tr>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <select class="form-control subject_selected" name="subject[]" id="subject"  data-uid="0">
                                                                     <option value=" ">---Select Subject---</option>
                                                                     @foreach($subject_list as  $subject)
                                                                         <option value="{{ $subject->id }}">{{ $subject->SubjectName }}</option>
                                                                     @endforeach
                                                                 </select>
                                                             </td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <select class="form-control topic_selected" name="topic[]" id="topic"  data-uid="0">
                                                                 </select>
                                                             </td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Amount[]" id="Amount"/>
                                                             </td>
                                                             <td>
                                                                 <a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="btn btn-danger remove">X</a>
                                                             </td>
                                                         </tr>
                                                     </tbody>
                                                   <tfoot>
                                                       <tr>
                                                           <td style="border: none"></td>
                                                           <td style="border: none"></td>
                                                           <td style="border: none"></td>
                                                           <td><button class="btn btn-success" id="add_student">SEND</button></td>
                                                       </tr>
                                                   </tfoot>
                                               </table
```

```html
class Topic extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = [
        'TopicName'.'Subject_id'
    ];

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function subject(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Subject::class);
    }
}


class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable ,HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
         'FullName'.'EmployeeNumber','password',
    ];

      .
      .
      .
      .
      .

    public  function buyers(){

       return $this->belongsToMany(Buyer::class)->withTimestamps();

    }

    public function students(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

}



class Student extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = [
        'FullName'.'School','Combination','Phone','Type','Stream'
    ];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function subjects(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Subject::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function topics(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Topic::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}

  
class Subject extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'SubjectName',
    ];

    public function students(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function topics(){
        return $this->hasMany(Topic::class);
    }
}
```

```html
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        /*$this->validate($request,[
              'FullName' => 'requred|string',
             
        ]);*/

        $student = new Student();
        $student->FullName = $request->input('FullName');
   
          .
          .
          .
          .;
        $id = $student->save();

        //$user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);

        if ($id != 0){

            $condition = $request->input('subject');

             /*$student->subjects()->create([
                 'subject_name'=>$request->input('subject')
             ]);*/

            foreach ( $condition as $key => $av){
                $data =array([
                    'subject_id' => $request->input('subject')[$key],
                    'subject_name' => $request->input('subject')[$key],
                    'topic_name' => $request->input('topic')[$key],
                    'Price' => $request->input('Amount')[$key]
                ]);
                $student->subjects()->attach($data);
            }
        }
        return Response()->json($student);
    }
```

Comment: Topic and subject have to be created, too? Or are topic and subject selected from a predefined list and do already exist in the db?
Please add your Models and the request data to the question.

Comment: Topic and subject has already been created and they got subject and their respective topics  with db... i can fetch them through ajax request to dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it my self as follows

```html
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
   
        $student = new Student();
        $student->FullName = $request->input('FullName');
          .
          .
          .
        $student->Stream = $request->input('Stream');
        $id = $student->save();


        if ($id != 0){

            $condition = $request->subject;  //ACCESS SUBJECT NAME ARRAY subject[]
            $condition1 = $request->topic;  //ACCESS SUBJECT NAME ARRAY topic[]
            foreach ( $condition as $key => $av){
                $data =array([
                    'subject_id' => $request->subject[$key]
                ]);
                $student->subjects()->attach($data);
            }

            foreach ( $condition1 as $key_topic => $av_topic){
                $data2 = array([
                    'topic_id' => $request->topic[$key_topic],
                    'Price' => $request->Amount [$key_topic]
                ]);
                $student->topics()->attach($data2);
            }
            $student->users()->attach(auth()->user()->id);
        }


        $status =  'Failed To Register' ;
        if($student){
            $status =  'Student Successfully Added';
        }
        return redirect()->back()->with('status' ,$status);
    }
```